# How to get Application to Extension Mappings

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, isolatedstorage

I have an application that allows users to save files to Isolated Storage. The application will display all files, in similar fashion to the file explorer and will allow a user to double click the file in order to view it.

Is there a way to grab all application-to-extension mappings from windows and fire up the right application whenever a file is clicked? This of course will be based on the extension of the file....

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to open a file with default handling:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi= new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("c:\\afile.txt");
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Verb = "open";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

This corresponds to API call:

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "C:\\afile.txt", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```